# How do I activate Google Translate in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

When I go on a page that's totally in a foreign language the "do you want to translate" option comes up but how do I make Chrome translate a page that has 90% English and a few lines in another language. Is there a button I can install or something because the Google Translate thing doesn't come up when only a few sentences are in another language.

OS: 4.1
S3

Comment: This drives me mad to be honest, I end up copying and pasting from Chrome to Google Translate app when this happens. I'd love to see a workaround to this issue.

Comment: Check this ; https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3214105?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

Go to `chrome://flags/#translate-android-manual-trigger` (copy paste into your browser) and enable this feature. After relaunch, you'll see the new "translate" option in the menu.

Comment: This isn't working as of June 2019.

Answer (score 4):

With the latest Google Translate update, you can **Enable Tap to Translate** feature in Google Translate **Settings**.

In chrome, long press the text you want to translate and choose **copy**. A google translate icon will appear in the window and you just tap it to see the translation. In this way, you no need to switch between two apps :)

Answer (score 3):

In my  device（nexus 5）
I have Google translate and chrome.
if i want translate words→long  press →share→translate them.
you can try it. :)

ps: Forgot my poor English.

Comment: This approach saves me three steps :)

Comment: You can also use the share option in the chrome menu and translate the whole page.

Comment: Sadly this won't work for me on a text-heavy page like an article as it seems to have a short length limit, it only shows the first two paragraphs or so of translated text followed by an ellipsis. The optiok to share or copy the translation does not allow you to get the rest translated.